# My Apple push notifications stopped with Java Apns stopped working

Tags: apple-push-notifications, javaapns

Since the April 1st 2021, my Apple push notifications with [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) stopped working, i.e my devices wouldn't receive push notification anymore, while my backend server using the java-apns library wouldn't throw any exceptions... I've checked my `.p12` certificates and they have not expired, so I am quite unsure as to what's happening?
Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [java-apns github page](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) says:

> ### Warning
>
> Apple will no longer support the legacy binary protocol after March 31, 2021. Java-Apns will stop working. See [details](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=uzyxiriy) in their announcement.
>
> It is recommended to use [Pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy) instead, which supports Apple's HTTP/2-based APNs protocol.

So basically the library stop working, as it uses a protocol that us no longer supported and you  can try [migrate to Pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy/wiki/Migrating-from-java-apns) or any other libraries.